# Storm Call - Qo casts itself without knowing the word?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, mods

I was just fighting a dragon outside of Windhelm, when suddenly it seemed like I uttered a Word of power and fiery stones started raining from the sky. I managed to drink a Waterbreathing potion and hide under ice until it passed. I don't know this Word and didn't shout - I was simply running around trying to hit the dragon with lightning bolt. When I opened my status screen, this is what I saw:

[image: Storm call - QO - +10 CG Dragon Storm Call Self 45 secs]

Can someone please care to elaborate? :)

Comment: What mods are you using, especially those related to dragons?

Comment: whatever mods that is, sounds AWESOME :P

Comment: I'm using the Dragon combat overhaul.

Comment: While fighting Alduin in Sovngarde, if you open the Active Effects menu, something similar shows up, which is due to Alduin Shouting (thus producing the 'fiery stones' mentioned). I think in this case too, it is the dragon, and not you who had Shouted.

Comment: @BlackHawk that's what I concluded in the end - what confused me is the graphics of shout coming from my body, as if I uttered the word.. weird

Answer (score 1):

The reason is, The game stylises this as you shouting it, but actually when fighting a dragon, this can happen. Just a little glitch, but it still looks cool!